# Is it possible to get play statistics from an album of videos using the Vimeo API?

Tags: vimeo-api

We have a request from someone on our internal team to send a monthly report of play count for a set of videos that we have grouped in an album.

I think this is something we're going to be asked to do for several different groups so I was hoping to write a program that would handle this for me.

Glancing through the Vimeo API, I didn't see anything relating to pulling up analytic or usage data.

Am I missing something obvious? Or is that capability just not there?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new api (developer.vimeo.com/api) play stats are included in each clip response.

So if you made an HTTP GET request to /me/albums/[album_id]/videos, you should be able to loop through the videos (and through multiple pages if necessary) and pull out the play data.

We don't expose much more than the play data yet, but there will soon be Advanced Stats exposed through the API, just like on site.

Comment: Are the Advanced Stats exposed in the API yet? We would like to retrieve weekly stats, e.g. plays and likes, for our videos via the API.

Comment: It was delayed for an abundance of reasons, but we're working on it. We are hoping to launch it mid 2015.

Comment: Hello Guys, I can see all other stats like likes, comments etc. but plays are null. Is there any way to get the "plays" statistics ?

Comment: Hi Dashron, some videos expose the plays statistic and some do not. Is there any reason for that ?

Comment: Users can opt out of sharing their play data publicly. This is the only time that field will be null.