# API for Vimeo doesn't have a count for the number of finishes ?

Tags: vimeo

The number of viewers who haved watched a video is easily accessible from the API from `videos -> stats/plays` but I would also like to retrieve the number of viewers who have watched the video to the end. How do I retrieve this statistic ? It is easily accessible from the website, but I can't find it in the returned stats.

Answer (score 0):

Only the number of plays via the GET video API call for now. https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_video

If you want to download a table with stats, you will need to log in at your vimeo dashboard ..

@see [How to get video stats via vimeo api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859829/how-to-get-video-stats-via-vimeo-api)
and [Is it possible to get play statistics from an album of videos using the Vimeo API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274137/is-it-possible-to-get-play-statistics-from-an-album-of-videos-using-the-vimeo-ap/23297445)