# How to get video stats via vimeo api

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I want to get stats of videos in my vimeo account through api call. 
I'm using 
**https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos/stats**  endpoint to get stats as described in their documentation.
And I'm getting this response

**{
    "error": "Your access token does not have the \"stats\" scope"
}**

and there is no option to add stats scope at apps dashboard

Comment: Can you share the piece of code which make the call?

Comment: I'm making  the test call at their api playground https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/me/videos/stats
so no coding involve.

Comment: If the question isn't related to code, but rather the Vimeo API specifically, I would encourage you to consult their documentation and support community instead. It's likely we don't have enough information to address your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Full stats are not yet available via the public Vimeo API.

The only stats returned by the API is a video's total play stat, which is returned on the /videos/[video_id] endpoint, documented here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#GET/videos/{video_id}

Detailed stats can only be retrieved on-site: https://vimeo.com/stats

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation